# Taking purchases for physical products within an iPhone app

Tags: cordova, paypal, payment-gateway

I am making an app whereby a customer can browse a catalogue of physical products (which I will ship to them). I am still deciding what payment gateway to use... after doing research I have decided the two best options are PayPal Express Checkout (mobile integration) or Zooz.

I am developing the app using PhoneGap, and noticed Zooz have released a plugin for PhoneGap which is great, just wondered if I can DEFINITELY sell physical products using this? I see a lot about In-App purchases when researching this, and I know that is not what I want, but people seem to see In-app purchasing and physical products as the same thing. I can sell physical stuff with Zooz right?

Also any experiences of either options would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sell physical goods with any payment gateway.  I think what you're seeing about in-app purchases is that Apple won't approve such applications unless you use their payment options.  So you could still build the app using whatever gateway you want, but you wouldn't be able to get it added to the iTunes store.  You'd just have to distribute it yourself.